# Java3D Texture Brightness

Tags: textures, brightness

Im displaying images in a 3D environment by using them as a texture on a QuadArray object, which works fine so far. But now I want to "dim" the texture I used, so that the resulting picture is displayed darker than before (I need that to display the backsides of the pictures in the 3D environment; for that purpose I create a second QuadArray object with the same texture, just mirrored and darker so that the user knows that it't the backside he's looking at). How can I do this?
I fiddled around with using ColoringAttributes, TransparencyAttributes + colored QuadArray, Materials and TextureAttributes for hours but everytime the backside is just as bright as the frontside... Whats the normal way to achieve what I want?

Here's the code for creating the backside of the picture and some commented out stuff I tried already. Im using white ambient light btw.

```
QuadArray plane2 = new QuadArray(4, QuadArray.COORDINATES | GeometryArray.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_2 | GeometryArray.ALLOW_COLOR_WRITE | QuadArray.COLOR_3 | Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS);
        plane2.setColor(0, new Color3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
        plane2.setColor(1, new Color3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
        plane2.setColor(2, new Color3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
        plane2.setColor(3, new Color3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
        plane2.setCoordinate (3, new Point3f (-0.005f * image.getWidth(), -0.005f * image.getHeight(), 0f));
        plane2.setCoordinate (2, new Point3f (0.005f * image.getWidth(), -0.005f * image.getHeight(), 0f));
        plane2.setCoordinate (1, new Point3f (0.005f * image.getWidth(), 0.005f * image.getHeight(), 0f));
        plane2.setCoordinate (0, new Point3f (-0.005f * image.getWidth(), 0.005f * image.getHeight(), 0f));
        plane2.setTextureCoordinate (0, 3, new TexCoord2f(0f,0f));
        plane2.setTextureCoordinate (0, 2, new TexCoord2f(1f,0f)); 
        plane2.setTextureCoordinate (0, 1, new TexCoord2f(1f,1f));
        plane2.setTextureCoordinate (0, 0, new TexCoord2f(0f,1f));
        Appearance planeAppearance2 = new Appearance();
        planeAppearance2.setTexture(image);
        // Material material = new Material();
        // material.setAmbientColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        TextureAttributes tex = new TextureAttributes();
        tex.setTextureMode(TextureAttributes.BLEND);
        tex.setTextureBlendColor(.0f, .0f, .0f, .5f);
        planeAppearance2.setTextureAttributes(tex);
        // TransparencyAttributes tAtt = new TransparencyAttributes(TransparencyAttributes.BLENDED, 0.0f); //BLENDED
        // planeAppearance2.setTransparencyAttributes(tAtt);
        // planeAppearance2.setMaterial(material);
        // planeAppearance2.setColoringAttributes(new ColoringAttributes(1f, 0.f, 0.f, ColoringAttributes.NICEST));

        objectTG.addChild(new Shape3D (plane2, planeAppearance2));
```